Getting around in Portugal by public transport
I am planning a ten-day trip to Portugal for next May. We will arrive by plane, then we will travel by train and bus.
I would like to avoid traveling too often with luggage so I ask for advice if it would be enough to stay a few days in Lisbon and a few in Porto, then move on to day trips.
I also ask in which areas of Lisbon and Porto it is best to look for accommodation to use public transport.

Metro in Lisbon is cheap and you can pay with a regular credit card. Can be full at rush hour. Last time I was there (2 weeks ago), the Metro went on strike so we had to take an Uber to the airport (which  was also reasonably inexpensive).

I've had no trouble in several trips to Portugal using only public transit. Metro in the cities and Flixbus between (and a very occasional ride hailing trip, if memory serves). There are trains too, but I don't recall taking one. Been to Lisbon, Sintra, Porto, Coimbra, Faro and (walking) many smaller places between Porto and Spain along the Camino. Some excursions had transportation provided (eg. to a winery).
The metro works fine to and from the airport in Lisbon and Porto, and you can stay wherever you like near a metro stop from the pov of transportation assuming reasonable luggage. You may prefer one area or another for other reasons.
For in-city transportation, the metro lines are clean, well marked, safe and inexpensive. No problem at all. Lisbon and Porto are quite walkable if you don't mind climbing a bit here and there. Google maps directions should give you an idea of elevation change if you're looking at the route from metro station to hotel.
Of course you'd get a different kind of a trip with a rental car, more access to various things in the countryside.. which is better depends on personal preferences. As far as day trips go- troll the tour sites and see what is on offer to get an idea of what is popular and practical. Some can be duplicated on public transit, others less so.

We are not travel agents, buuuuut....
Your 'would be enough' carries a lot of weight. :)
It is certainly possible to only book accommodation in both Lisbon and Porto. In fact both of these cities could easily warrant a 10 day stay on their own. For both, there are also plenty destinations fit for a day trip.
You could also consider a stop between these two cities. Coimbra, for example.
For convenience, find a place that's fairly close to a metro station. Just compare a map of the metro network with the availability of accommodation on your platform of choice.
